# How to use str_view in a loop

Tags: r, regex, string, nlp, stringr

I have a **very** large data vector of comments, and regex patterns I computed that identify interesting information from the comments. I wish to QA my REGEX on the comments sequentially. I planned to work on the vector with a loop, each time taking the i'th cell into str_view but this method failed. any insight will be welcome.

example code that works but does not allow me to see the entire length of results:

```
library(stringr)


a<-c("yo","do","you","have","food?")
str_view(a,"o")
```

failes:

```
library(stringr)

a<-c("yo","do","you","have","food?")

for (i in (1:5)){str_view(a[i],"o")}
```

Comment: What's the problem? The loop works as in `for (i in (1:length(a))) print(c(a[i],"o"))`.

Comment: How do you plan to view each in the `Viewer` tab?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the aim, we can use `Map`. One can view each result by clicking the back button assuming you're using RStudio. :

```
Map(function(x) str_view(x,"o"),a)
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a print.  This will print alot?  How did you want it outputted?

```
library(stringr)

a<-c("yo","do","you","have","food?")

for (i in (1:5)){ print( str_view(a[i],"o"))}
```